# Gridview Databind Very Slow

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Am Using asp.net gridview small amount of data load to grid is not a problem but bulk amount of data load to grid i facing slowness issue. how to avoid ?

and i am using sqldataadapter and fill to datatable and bind to gridview

Comment: There is only one way to avoid performance problems: find out what takes too long, then fix it. Have you determined exactly what part of your code is taking too long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem returning about 9000 rows with a datasource accessing a stored procedure.  The sproc runs fast, but would run slow when it was databound to a gridview.

I removed the `order by` clause in the stored procedure and it's lighting fast.  Eveidently the grid wants to do it's own ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do two queries, the first is to get the total count of the records in all the pages for your grid view (this is the large amount that is causing your data bind to be very slow). After getting this total count, then you need to calculate the total number of pages that will be available to your pager control. Finally, you need to make a query for the individual page of data you want to retrieve from the server.

For example, if your grid view has 1,000 total rows (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable`) and you want to have pages that show 25 rows per page, then you will have 40 pages (`1,000 / 25 = 40`) of data and any single request for a page of data will only return 25 records instead of all 1,000 records.

For a walkthrough of implementing this logic, read [Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445510.aspx).

---

UPDATE:

If you are not interested in the pager control, then you can implement an infinite scroll type interface, where as the user scrolls down the page, then the next page of data is fetched from the server. Read [Load Content While Scrolling With jQuery](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/) for more information.

Comment: any idea without page control

Comment: @Senthilkumar - see `UPDATE` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to display many thousand records at once - this could be major reason for performance issues. One way to alleviate this is to retrieve data into a DataTable, cache that datatable and use it in paging to display, say 50 records per page. (this way you won't have to hit database for every page change/rebind).

And even this approach works for limited number of records, if that number becomes huge - even retrieving all records into in-memory DataTable is not an option, you will have to implement server-side paging to retrieve only a portion of data from DB at a time.

That said, another common reason for slowdown when query is called from .NET code vs. direct execution in SSMS could be parameter sniffing. If SQL Server built and cached execution plan that is not optimal for curent query execution - it may really slow it down. Try adding following line at the end of your code that builds SQL Statement:

Answer (score 1):

That calls for server side paging. What that means is that your gridview would load only 10/15 entries per page. When you would click the next page, it would again hit your database & bring the next 10 records. Takes a little time setting up but definitely worth it. You will have great performance. [Efficiently Paging through large results](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506081930/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041206-1.shtml)